# bash: cpan: command not found

Tags: perl, centos, cpan, yum

I need to install few perl modules on web hosting server ( OS: Cent OS 6.4, perl v5.10.1) using ssh.

On server :

```
cpan -i Template::Toolkit
```

Is giving error:

```
bash: cpan: command not found
```

command `perl -v` is showing that perl is installed, then how is that possible cpan isn't.
Or do i need to add some path or change env setting.

env variable **PATH** value is

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin

Comment: Where is perl running from? Try `type perl` or `which perl`.

Comment: @choroba perl is running from /usr/bin/perl

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to install it with yum,

```
yum install perl-CPAN
```

but you don't need it as `Template::Toolkit` is already in yum repository,

```
yum install perl-Template-Toolkit
```

Comment: @Bharat, try to edit `/etc/yum/pluginconf.d/priorities.conf` and set `enabled = 0` then try `yum update` again